# Do we need Three phase selector switch when you have Circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, switch, circuit-breaker

I see people are recommending to have **Three Phase Selector Switch** besides having circuit breaker.

3 Phase selector switch divides electric supply for different rooms. When we have circuit breaker which also gives supply to specific areas then why should we go for this selector switch ?

In factories , it might help shift voltage or something ..

Are there any considerable advantage for residence ?

Can someone help me understand this ?

Update:

Fig: 3 phase selector switch

[image]

Comment: For a residence probably not since only a very few have three phase power in North America.  Have not google three phase selector switch, but I imagine it is not what you think it is.  It is probably something a lot more complicated, than switching power to different rooms/circuits.

Comment: Where in the world are you located?

Comment: I have had 3 phase power to my homes for 30 years. For a few reasons. 1) I  needed more power than single phase 230v/63Amps because my wife's kiln takes 60Amps. 2) Previous house had a water feature with 3 phase pump, this one has a 3 phase induction hob. 3) It lets me control solar power and generator by putting them on different phases. Its not to switch power from one room to another. Its about the demand for extra power.

Comment: @RohitGupta - I understand 3 phase is more power. My house has 3 phase electric power. But I am not seeing 3 phase selector switch , I'm just wondering if it's necessary to have 3 phase switch. I have so many expensive electric appliances at home and I want to be bit proactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is used change the phase assignment, allowing you to choose the used phase for certain subdivision of your installation.

That would make sense if regularly an phase fails, or if one needs to constantly balance the load across the phases.

That must be something related to your local electrical power grid. I am also from an 3phase place, and I never saw such a thing.

We distribute the phases upon installation, according to their expected load. The local power company tolerates phase imbalance from consumers or small loads
Also, the grid is quite reliable. When power fails, it fails on all phases.

Also, should you use 3phase motors, such devices could be dangerous, as electric 3phase motors get damaged by applying the same phase on different windings.

Should it happen regularly that one or two phases fail, such an switch might be an good investment. But first I'd make sure to have

- The proper circuit breakers
- Everything covered by RCDs.
- Perhaps an surge protector
- And ideally some AFDD
- And a double or triple checked neutral in the 3phase part of your installation. As an fault in the neutral will swiftly kill your appliances by applying 400V on them. Read "lost neutral".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and mentioning about lost neutral, risks of switch in 3 phase motor and AFDD , it helps a lot.